# Programmatically setting a new menu item ID

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two problems that I'm guessing will be solved by the same solution. I have a menu that has a default set of menu options, in addition to this depending on the user permissions I add additional menu items using the code below;

```
Menu m = navView.getMenu();
        SubMenu menuGroup = m.addSubMenu("Manager Area");
        menuGroup .add("My Matches");
        menuGroup .add("Contact Info");
```

I need to do 2 things;

- Assign a ID to both the two new menu items
- Remove those ID's (I think I already know how, but without a ID for each menu its impossible to reference).

I can see when using the intellisense in Android studio that I can set additional parameters but every time I try it tells me its wrong.

Comment: "_every time I try it tells me its wrong_" Can you tell us the _exact_ error messages you are getting?

Comment: I don't get an error when running it, the code underlines red in Android Studio :)

Comment: And when you hover over that it should be showing you a message about what the problem is. Also, when asking about code that gives a problem you should show that code here.

Comment: I found the anwser; menu.add(0, 2, 0, "My Matches").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem;

```
menu.add(0, 2, 0, "My Matches")
```

This allowed me to set a numeric ID against each menu item.